# Typescript generic callback with arguments that extend an interface, TS2345

Tags: interface, callback, arguments, extend, typescript-generics

How can I create a callback that takes arguments, where the arguments can be anything that extends some interface, but apart from that I don't know the exact type ?

e.g.

```js
const fnct = function( data: DataAny, callback: GenericCallback<DataAny> ): void {
    callback( data );
};
// DataAny here should be like "argument type that can be anything but has to extend DataAny"
```

### Example

To be more specific, how can I avoid the typescript errors in the last two lines here
*(maybe easiest to read from bottom up)*:

```js
// -- unchangeable interface, comes from external library --
interface DataAny {
    type: string;
    [more: string]: any;
}

// -- my interfaces / types --
interface DataBook extends DataAny { pages: number }
interface DataWater extends DataAny { liters: number }

type GetQuantity<D> = ( data: D ) => void; // callback function type

// -- generic function --
const genericQuantityInfo = function( data: DataAny, f: GetQuantity<DataAny> ): void {
    console.log('quantity: ', f( data ));
};

// -- data --
const book: DataBook  = { type: 'book',  pages: 303 };
const water: DataWater = { type: 'water', liters: 12 };

// -- callbacks --
const getQuantityBook: GetQuantity<DataBook>  = function( data: DataBook ){ return data.pages + ' pages'; };
const getQuantityWater: GetQuantity<DataWater> = function( data: DataWater ){ return data.liters + ' liters'; };

// -- calls --
genericQuantityInfo( book,  getQuantityBook ); // <-- error TS2345: 'GetQuantity<DataBook>' is not assignable to 'GetQuantity<DataAny>'. 'pages' is missing in 'DataAny' but required in 'DataBook'
genericQuantityInfo( water, getQuantityWater ); // <-- error (similar to above)
```

### *Not* wanted

Note that I can **not** pass the specific types, like `genericQuantityInfo<DataBook>` here (this works):

```js
const genericQuantityInfo = function<T>( data: T, f: GetQuantity<T> ): void { console.log('quantity: ', f( data )); };
genericQuantityInfo<DataBook>( book,  getQuantityBook );
genericQuantityInfo<DataWater>( water, getQuantityWater );
```

The **reason** why I can't do this is that my use case is actually more complex, using a creator function, and I don't want to pass all possible types `<DataBook | DataWater | ...` (also I couldn't get this to work as well). like:

```js
const creator = function<T>(){
    return function( data: T, f: GetQuantity<T> ): void {
        console.log('quantity: ', f( data ));
    };
};
creator<DataBook | DataWater /* | ... */ >()(book, getQuantityBook); // <-- still error anyway
```

But as I simplified a lot here, any Ideas on where I misunderstood something are also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: yes, thanks. You answered my question, and it helped me to proceed. I got the same error further up now, but was not part of my simplified question. I am trying to understand and apply your idea in other places now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it:

Instead of typing as `DataAny` try to type it as `T extends DataAny` it means anything that has `DataAny` props.

```js
interface DataAny {
    type: string;
    [more: string]: any;
}

// -- my interfaces / types --
interface DataBook extends DataAny { pages: number }
interface DataWater extends DataAny { liters: number }

type GetQuantity<D extends DataAny> = ( data: D ) => void; // callback function type

// -- generic function --
const genericQuantityInfo = function<T extends DataAny>( data: T, f: GetQuantity<T> ): void {
    console.log('quantity: ', f( data ));
};

// -- data --
const book: DataBook  = { type: 'book',  pages: 303 };
const water: DataWater = { type: 'water', liters: 12 };

// -- callbacks --
const getQuantityBook: GetQuantity<DataBook>  = function( data: DataBook ){ return data.pages + ' pages'; };
const getQuantityWater: GetQuantity<DataWater> = function( data: DataWater ){ return data.liters + ' liters'; };

// -- calls --
genericQuantityInfo( book,  getQuantityBook ); // OK
genericQuantityInfo( water, getQuantityWater ); // OK
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=27&ssc=49&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAgiAnsgbwChlTkxcAHCALmQGcwpQBzAbhLIG0BbAeyi0GTVgF06cPBwC%20RIgHp5yALTLkPfKEixEEesiUVq%201US3R4SNBjgAhPnwDWyCAA9IIACb70mHPgJkSjgWPToQAFceACNoZFlzHStfOAB1DDi3D29rPzxCZAAbYG16cKjYqHi5IxQAcQgwAEUIyTAS3AAeVBd3CC8fG38APmQAXmQACmRPGzoegEpx0YA3PmBPNgMlBDhCwujEZxgIkAR2vhByKgg5RRU1UJBoYARkE7OLq9MES8ZkJ4vBAtNodACSIBgfHG71O52Al06ABVetlBnlcMNprNMHQkQAad50BrNVrgDrI0YLOhrDaETikX4geh8QoQAB0hT4LEmAHIAI5k9oUOi8wkwbE2ZALBYyDgKJSqGZSn5-MDIaIORzzGz2JykCaBWqizVOMWkYKhMrIADMAAYbfEOEz-gB3DJQHWYdLaGFGm6i93ac3FUp0ACMACYnXdFWpdvtDghHCZlEQXerQqTQRQ9drkCSQeSKN1dVrRjCPvDLpLcbk7FrpYFBGAIlArji4OzLXpkABqZC8oIhPS8rbSZ1qgGNIvC3A%206DEmdCikpBdQUYTKtfWtwL1pD1N5AttsdmyckrQfQDoehq9jmMKh7IBOFVNEQHMYErigQqHTU1HEJads2LXA82lLZ7k6JVoCgARkCRABlSMbQAFgAVlFQsfy6FI82GIdgH0EA%20HVOB6HoYAWBAOBojZchoV5HCczwoY8EI9lBx7egiP0HhiKokAWGQUBBxSfwh2iCJ1UEQVgEETxRKuXl8K1XkP36IFZ3BSE%20GmINoEJLMdIoddIOQIA)